# VB.NET Cannot get Integer from String

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing

This is really strange:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String = "48;55;50"
Dim numbers() As String = Split(s, ";")
For Each number In numbers
    i = Integer.Parse(number)
Next
```

This works for the the first item in numbers (48) but not for the second number (55). I get a FormatException.

Tried using CInt instead of Integer.Parse. Even tried using s.Split instead of Split.

I really don't get it. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint on the line where `i` is assigned?

Comment: Yes I did. Checked all variables. It doesn't makes sense at all.

Comment: What did `number`contain when the breakpoint was hit?

Comment: First i is set to 0 (default). Then it's 48 after the first run.

Comment: But what does `number` contain?

Comment: What do you mean by that ? number is an Integer and its value is 48 after the first run. Or do you mean "numbers", the string array ?

Comment: It works. Consider to declare "number as string" in for, and do the split with Split(s, cchar(";") in order to discard type exceptions. Put a debug.print, etc.

Comment: Are you using another input array different to `"48;55;50"`?

Comment: Capitan, that didn't help either. Does it work on your machine ? @dbvega  That's exactly the code I use. I just c&p'ed

Comment: you are leaving something out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SEruOc

Comment: Yes. Copied and pasted, using a new windows form project, Vs2013.

Comment: @user2864740 that is one of those legacy VB functions - it would be in `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Comment: @AndersLindén Do go on..

Comment: I replaced line 3 with: Dim numbers = Split(s, ";") and it's working now. Mh strange. Thanks guys

Comment: This code works. I suspect something with your "option explicit" or something like that. I would normally write `For Each number as String in...`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using `Split` method in `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, if you really feel like:

```
Dim s As String = "23;43;34"

For Each num As String In Regex.Split(s, ";")
    Console.WriteLine(Integer.Parse(num))
Next
```

On short amount of data, there shouldn't be any performance difference, so it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It must work for you (RemoveEmptyEntries)

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As String = "48;55;50;"
Dim separator As Char() = ";"
Dim numbers As String() = s.Split(separator, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
For Each number In numbers
    i = Integer.Parse(number, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Next
```

Comment: Too much coding - OP's code works as written on properly set system